# What is the difference between NoExecute, NoSchedule, PreferNoSchedule?

Tags: kubernetes

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/ The docs are not very clear as to what exactly the values represent.

> the system will try to avoid placing a pod that does not tolerate the
>   taint on the node, but it is not required

What does 'try' imply? If I said a function will try sort a a list of numbers - it's not very clear...

Answer (score 35):

Although there is a slight difference, I like more Google explanation about what **Node Taints** are, rather then Kubernetes:

A node taint lets you mark a node so that the scheduler avoids or prevents using it for certain Pods. A complementary feature, tolerations, lets you designate Pods that can be used on "tainted" nodes.

Node taints are key-value pairs associated with an effect. Here are the available effects:

`NoSchedule`: Pods that do not tolerate this taint are not scheduled on the node.

`PreferNoSchedule`: Kubernetes avoids scheduling Pods that do not tolerate this taint onto the node. This one basically means, do it, if possible.

`NoExecute`: Pod is evicted from the node if it is already running on the node, and is not scheduled onto the node if it is not yet running on the node.

Note that the difference between `NoSchedule` and `NoExecute` is that with the first one  it won't schedule a pod, but if it is already running, it won't kill it. With the last one, it will kill the pod and re-schedule on another node.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that the definition of tolerations is counterintuitive? If a pod has a toleration defined as "key=mykey, operator=exist, effect=noschedule", then, read in natural language, this would mean that if key=mykey exists on the node, the effect would be that the pod will not be scheduled on that node. However, the opposite is the case.

Comment: @AlexanderStumpf yes. that's the opposite.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your question - which I understand it is regarding PreferNoSchedule - It means that it is not a strict requirement, in other words, if a pod is already scheduled on that node and it has that toleration effect, it won't be removed.

I would suggest you to dive into the [design proposals](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/930ce65595a3f7ce1c49acfac711fee3a25f5670/contributors/design-proposals/scheduling/taint-toleration-dedicated.md) docs if you are still confused, they clarified a lot of concepts for me.

Comment: What you just described is rather the difference between `NoSchedule `and `NoExecute`. `PreferNoSchedule` simply means it will _try_ to avoid scheduling the pod on that node, but it might sometimes happens (e.g. if all other nodes are "full").

Comment: If you are using PreferNoSchedule taint, your pod maybe will be scheduled in the node even withouth the correct Toleration. PreferNoSchedule means that the Kubernetes Scheduler will try avoid, but if all rules for schedules points the pod to this Node, this taint won't will take in place and the pod will be scheduled anyway.